# Redirect, if user Modifying URL or URL getting Change

Tags: javascript, jquery, address-bar, location-href

I want to redirect if User Manually edit URL.  My goal is prevent user, Modifying address bar URL.

is it possible to prevent ? or can I able to redirect to home page if they enter anything?

**for eg**:  my current url after login, **www.domain.com/user**

but if the user going to type **www.domain.com/admin** means, i want to redirect it back to user. because i dont want them to land in admin page login ...

Comment: So you want to lock up customers? For what? Are you planning to write Ransomware?

Comment: I really don't know your plan, but please, don't do that

Comment: I am having user based restriction. had backend restriction for specific url to specific users. if they typed it means i dont want to show even restricted . simply redirect into home page

Comment: @user do that if backend validation fails

Comment: i done that . can check again my question. it was edited. if user entering domain.com/admin i want to redirect in that case

Comment: @Jonasw is correct. If the user don't have permission to access /admin simply redirect to a url to which the user has access

Comment: @NidhinChandran thats i am asking. if they went through UI we can control them. if they type URL directly on address bar means what to do? how to control?

Comment: After user is logged in you are setting a session or cookie to identify the user, right ??? When ever the user is trying to access some url through address bar, hyperlinks or anything check if the user has permission to access url. You can do this by identifying the user with the session/cookie. If the user has permission allow to visit the url or just redirect to some other page. And for permissions i think you need to setup a privilege table with user id and permissions. I hope this will clear everything.

Comment: already mentioned that was done in backend. so, if the user enter manually backend will take care. even though i want to do the same in frontend itself. not to allow them if try to type manually